# AppDomain.ResourceResolve event

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, resources

MS Visual Studio, C#.

I need to locate all localized resource files into the .\resource subdirectory. I can't to use the probing XML element of config-file, i.e. my really project is dll (it will loaded in the external application and located not in the hosted application directory). I try to use the AppDomain.ResourceResolve event but I get a problem...

Now I wrote "Hello World" for showing it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace HelloWorld {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
      Thread thread = Thread.CurrentThread;
      thread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en");
      domain.ResourceResolve += domain_ResourceResolve;
      ResourceManager res = new ResourceManager(typeof(Program));
      Console.WriteLine(res.GetString("Message"));
      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
      Console.ReadKey();
      res.ReleaseAllResources();
    }

    static System.Reflection.Assembly domain_ResourceResolve(object sender,
      ResolveEventArgs args) {
      Assembly assembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
      String name = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location),
      String.Format("resources\\en\\{0}.resources.dll", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(
      assembly.Location)));
      if (!File.Exists(name)) {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' file not found.", name);
        return null;
      }
      else {
        Assembly result = Assembly.LoadFrom(name);
        if (result != null)
          Console.WriteLine("'{0}' loaded.", name);
        return result;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Program.resx is not exists i.e. if it exists the ResourceResolve event is not occur. Exist the Program.en.resx and Program.ru.resx files also. In the properties of my project I set the post-build event:

```
rmdir .\resources /S /Q
mkdir .\resources
move .\en .\resources\en
move .\ru .\resources\ru
```

My localized resource was found and loaded successfully, but I get an exception (look the screen)...

[image]

My "Hello World" project attached also: [sources](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7H_2Cq9tBXdVGFTTl9zY19tMWs/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Not using the return value of String.Format() is of course a bug.

Comment: I think (and I have a hope) a mistake in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I register my event handler on the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` instead of the `AppDomain.ResourceResolve` it works *successful*, but the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` generate *twice* in this case (I don't know why). This decision was found by @Josser - thank you. So problem is solved. If anybody knows why the `AppDomain.ResourceResolve` don't working in my case, and why the `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` generate *twice* - I will be grateful for the explanation.

Comment: Late response but maybe useful. "Beginning with the .NET Framework 4, the System.ResolveEventHandler event is raised for all assemblies, including resource assemblies. In earlier versions, the event was not raised for resource assemblies. If the operating system is localized, the handler might be called multiple times: once for each culture in the fallback chain." [http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.resolveeventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx]

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a different constructor:

```
ResourceManager res = new ResourceManager("Program", typeof(Program).Assembly);
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation can go a long way.